# Can't get grouping to work with sed

Tags: regex, sed, grouping, backreference, parentheses

This works as expected:

INPUT FILE src.txt:

```
ffmpeg -i uno.3gp
ffmpeg -i dos.3gp
ffmpeg -i tres.3gp
```

COMMAND:

```
sed 's/-i .*\./XXX/' <src.txt
```

RESULT AS EXPECTED:

```
ffmpeg XXX3gp
ffmpeg XXX3gp
ffmpeg XXX3gp
```

Then why don't these work as expected:

COMMAND:

```
sed 's/-i (.*)\./XXX/' <src.txt
```

EXPECTED:

```
ffmpeg XXX3gp
ffmpeg XXX3gp
ffmpeg XXX3gp
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
ffmpeg -i uno.3gp
ffmpeg -i dos.3gp
ffmpeg -i tres.3gp
```

COMMAND:

```
sed 's/-i (.*)\.3gp/\1.mp3/' <src.txt
```

EXPECTED:

```
ffmpeg uno.mp3
ffmpeg dos.mp3
ffmpeg tres.mp3
```

ACTUAL RESULT

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

The parenthesis don't seem to work for grouping, but all the tutorials and examples I've found around seem to assume they should...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Classic `sed` (not GNU `sed` necessarily), the grouping commands use `\(` and `\)` (and the counts use `\{` and `\}`) rather than unescaped.

Thus, you should try:

```
sed 's/-i \(.*\)\./XXX/' <src.txt
sed 's/-i \(.*\)\.3gp/\1.mp3/' <src.txt
```

Or, if you've got GNU `sed`, add `-r` or `--regexp-extended` to 'use extended regular expressions in the script' (quoting from `sed --help`).

```
sed -r 's/-i (.*)\./XXX/' <src.txt
sed -r 's/-i (.*)\.3gp/\1.mp3/' <src.txt
```

Comment: Great. I thought I had tried with slashes, but that was when I wasn't using apices '' so I had to escape everything with yet more slashes and I didn't get it right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan Leffler answered about the source of your error, I would like to mention, that backreference not always is good stuff, sometimes it is really slows down the script.

Furthermore in you case you don't need backreference at all:

```
sed 's/-i //;s/\.3gp/.mp3/' <src.txt
```

will do the job.

Comment: thank you but mine was just a silly minimized example to illustrate the issue ;)